# Almacenar registros codificados en un código QR mediante pistoleo a una tabla en MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un código QR el cual internamente tiene almacenados 100 registros en formato de filas (100 registros hacia abajo).
Y, mediante una pistola lectora de códigos, realizo la lectura e inserto los 100 registros en una tabla en MySQL. Hasta ahí todo funciona bien.

Código QR:
[image: Codigo QR con la lista de 1os 100 registros]

A continuación, especifico cómo realizo el proceso:

1. La lectura se realiza mediante el siguiente código HTML (input):
   Nota: El input tiene activada la funcion `onchange` para que ejecute la función llamada `valida_codigo_barra();`

```
    <div class="input-group form-group-sm">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-star" id="stylocss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ESCANEAR CODIGO DE BARRA / QR" title="ESCANEAR CODIGO DE BARRA / QR" name="codigo_barra" id="codigo_barra" autocomplete="off" onchange="valida_codigo_barra();">
    </div>
```

2. Función `valida_codigo_barra()`;
   Nota: esta función llama a un archivo PHP el cual se encarga de realizar el insert masivo

```
    function valida_codigo_barra() {
     var proveedor = document.getElementById("proveedor");
     var proveedor_value = proveedor.value;
     var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo_barra").value;
    
     if (proveedor_value === "" || proveedor_value === undefined) {
      BootstrapDialog.show({
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER, 
        title: 'CARGA DE DISPOSITIVOS TAG',
        message: 'PARA CONTINUAR, DEBE SELECCIONAR UN <b>PROVEEDOR</b>.<br />LUEGO, DEBE VOLVER A ESCANEAR EL CODIGO.'
      });
      $('#proveedor').focus();
      $('#codigo_barra').val('');
      $('#valida_proveedor').show('slow');
     } else {
      var incremento = 0;
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "../intranet/mantenedor/escaneo_articulo.php",
        data: "codigo="+codigo+"&proveedor="+proveedor_value,
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function() {
          limpia_input();
        },
        error: function() {
          BootstrapDialog.alert('Ha ocurrido un error interno');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          incremento++;
          if (data === 1) {
            BootstrapDialog.alert('Registro almacenado correctamente.');
          }
        }
      });
      // alert(incremento);
     }
    }
```

3. Archivo *escaneo_articulo.php*
   Nota: este archivo es invocado desde AJAX y se ejecuta correctamente realizando los 100 insert a la tabla en MySQL.

```
    <?php
        /* *** CONEXION AL MOTOR DE BD *** */
        include('../../datos/conexion.php');
        $conn = conectar_principal();
        
        /* *** VARIABLE METODO POST *** */
        // $salida="";
        // sleep(1);
        $codigo = $_POST['codigo'] . ",";
        $proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'];
    
        $query_values = "
            INSERT INTO core_rec_tag (
                PRO_ID,
                EST_ID,
                BOL_ID,
                TAG_CODIGO_BARRA,
                TAG_ESTADO,
                TAG_ESTADO_TXT,
                TAG_FEC_CREACION
            )
            VALUES (
                $proveedor,
                1,
                1,
                '$codigo',
                'Y',
                'activo',
                NOW()
            );
        ";
        $ejecucion = mysqli_query($conn, $query_values);
    
        $salida="";
        $incremental = 0;
        if ($ejecucion)
        {
            $incremental++;
        }
        $salida = $incremental;
    
        echo $salida;
    ?>
```

4. Registros en tabla MySQL
   Nota: Aquí es donde tengo el problema junto con la estrategia que se usa en el código AJAX.

[image: Vista con los registros almacenados en la tabla de MySQL]

5. Problema:
   Cuando se hace el `focus()` al input y tomo la pistola lectora de códigos de barras, se escanea el código QR, pero al hacer el insert masivo, cada registro se comienza a unir hacia el lado (como se observa en la imagen anterior).
   Creo que la estrategia que estoy implementando en el código AJAX no es la correcta.

Comment: Pregunta, estas haciendo un for por alguna parte, porque tiene el `incremento`?

Comment: Hola, gracias. Se dio el problema en la generación del codigo QR. La lectura estaba correctamente implementada. Os compartire el resultado por si a alguien más os sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Chicos.
Logre validar el caso mencionado.

El error estaba en la generación del código QR, la calidad del mismo no era la suficiente. Se aplico mejor calidad y todo anduvo bien.

Si alguien necesita el código fuente para leer códigos QR desde una pistola NETUM o cualquier otra y ejecutar una accion en el motor de BD, que lo consulte y encantado le comparto la información (fuentes).

[image: Integración con motor de BD]

[image: Escaneo para codigos de barra]

[image: Lectura codigo QR]

[image: Un poco de estadistica]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).